# CSV Cell contain Python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The csv cell contain list with multiple dictionaries.

[image]

Now when I am reading this in python it is reading it as a string. But now I want to iterate through elements according to keywords. ow to get it?

```
dict = df['items'][0]
print(type(dict))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: this is csv file i want to access its value in python

Comment: sidenote: have a look at the edit, you should use formatted text as code instead of linking images.

Comment: Try `import json` and then `dict = json.loads(df['items'][0])`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads

Comment: Awesome.  If you're stuck with those inputs then so be it, but you might also want to consider other more appropriate formats if you can help it:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

`from ast import literal_eval
dict = literal_eval(df['items][0])
print(type(dict))`

output:
class 'list'

**literal_eval** library is used to read list from csv.

@mikewatt from the comments helped me with the reference.
This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: BTW, you should avoid giving variables the same name as Python built-ins, such as `dict`, because besides being confusing, it can lead to hard-to-find bugs or other problems—it also "hides" the built-in, so it can't be used if necessary.

Comment: @Debugger two things: here on stackoverflow (and stackexchange sites as well) is discouraged to thanks people the way you do (instead use the upvote feature on questions, comments, answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Also if an answer solved your issue you should accept it (click to make the check symbol green), so please check your own answer. Welcome.

Comment: @paolo thank you for guiding me, as i am new here that's why i am having problem with these things, actually in peoples comments i cannot be able to find the upvote option.

Comment: you are welcome. IIRC you need to reach 15 reputation score to be able to upvote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. regards

Comment: @Paolo okay now i get it, after reaching to 15 reputation i will use this option